# Can I get LIME to work with my BERT regression model?

Tags: python, pytorch, regression, bert-language-model, lime

I am getting a somewhat inscrutable error every time I true to run the `LIME` text explainer on my `BERT` regression model. Basically, the `BERT` model produces a numerical prediction just fine for any text I supply it with, but when the `LIME` text explainer uses the model it causes it to generate this error:

```
ValueError: only one element tensors can be converted to Python scalars
```

I import my libraries and model as follows:

```
import lime
import torch
from lime.lime_text import LimeTextExplainer
explainer = LimeTextExplainer()

from transformers import AutoModelForSequenceClassification, AutoTokenizer

# Load the saved BERT model and tokenizer
loaded_model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("/path/to/model")
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
```

I then define a `prediction` function for my `BERT` model:

```
def predict(text):
    inputs = tokenizer(text, padding=True, truncation=True, return_tensors="pt", max_length=128)
    loaded_model.eval()
    with torch.no_grad():
        outputs = loaded_model(**inputs)
        predicted_value = outputs.logits.item()
        return predicted_value
```

I test it and it works fine:

```
text_to_interpret = "We're flying high, watching the world pass us by."
predict(text_to_interpret)
>0.01548099610954523
```

However, when I instantiate a `LIME` text explainer, I get the error below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/zp/g2cg0s7d3vn0y092tw5x90rc0000gn/T/ipykernel_43525/1810001145.py in <module>
----> 1 explanation = explainer.explain_instance(text_to_interpret, predict)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lime/lime_text.py in explain_instance(self, text_instance, classifier_fn, labels, top_labels, num_features, num_samples, distance_metric, model_regressor)
    411                                         mask_string=self.mask_string))
    412         domain_mapper = TextDomainMapper(indexed_string)
--> 413         data, yss, distances = self.__data_labels_distances(
    414             indexed_string, classifier_fn, num_samples,
    415             distance_metric=distance_metric)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lime/lime_text.py in __data_labels_distances(self, indexed_string, classifier_fn, num_samples, distance_metric)
    480             data[i, inactive] = 0
    481             inverse_data.append(indexed_string.inverse_removing(inactive))
--> 482         labels = classifier_fn(inverse_data)
    483         distances = distance_fn(sp.sparse.csr_matrix(data))
    484         return data, labels, distances

/var/folders/zp/g2cg0s7d3vn0y092tw5x90rc0000gn/T/ipykernel_43525/1417496559.py in predict(text)
      4     with torch.no_grad():
      5         outputs = loaded_model(**inputs)
----> 6         predicted_value = outputs.logits.item()
      7         return predicted_value
      8 

ValueError: only one element tensors can be converted to Python scalars
```

I don't know whether this is an issue with `LIME` or with my `BERT` model. The model seems to work just fine on its own, so that makes me think it's `LIME`. But then the error is clearly a `Torch` tensor that can't be converted to a scalar.

I've tried wrapping the `predict` function in a `try except`, and converting dud outputs into `np.nan` values, but that's giving me other errors.

Can anyone help with this?